# Lazy match for a pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given string `1.blah blah2.yada yada` I'd like to extract `1.blah blah` and `2.yada yada`. I tried this `\d\..+` but that matches the entire string. `\d\..+?` matches `1.b` and `2.y`. I just need to match the pattern lazily. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+` at the end of the pattern matches all 1+ chars other than line break chars up to the string/line end. `.+?` at the end of the pattern only matches 1 char (but it is required) since `+?` is a lazy quantifier requiring only 1 char to be present.

You may use

```
\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cjswi0/1). Add `re.DOTALL` modifier if there can be line breaks inside the string.

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (if `re.DOTALL` is used, even including line break chars), as few as possible, up to (but excluding) the first occurrence of...
- `(?=\d+\.|$)` - (a positive lookahead matching either of the two alternatives:) 1+ digits and then `.` or end of string.

Python demo:

```
import re
rx = r"\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|$)"
s = "1.blah blah2.yada yada3.yadddaaa"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['1.blah blah', '2.yada yada', '3.yadddaaa']
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/TJC89581).